# Clip path does not work properly on Safari

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to add clip path to my div element. That works perfectly on chrome but behaves abnormally on safari.

Here is my code:

```
<div _ngcontent-hke-c9="" class="d-flex clip-box" style="-webkit-clip-path: circle(7px at 593px 58.5px);"></div>
```

You can find it in working state here:

> https://vibhorgoyal18.github.io/vibhor-goyal-portfolio/#/

Answer (score 1):

Clip path is only partially supported *(with -webkit prefix)* on Safari 7+. You can check the browser support [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)